# Можно ли заменять двоеточие на тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Есть у меня такое, я двоеточие ставлю редко, не люблю я его. Да и в школе нам преподавали на эту тему обтекаемо: хотите - ставьте тире, хотите - двоеточие. Вроде как не ошибка.
Так же на эту тему нашла тут статью:

> Например, в последнее время все чаще
> употребляется тире (на месте
> двоеточия) между частями бессоюзного
> сложного предложения при обозначении
> пояснения, причины во второй части,
> при обобщающих словах перед
> перечислением однородных членов и
> т.д.: Под развесистой кроной не бывает
> пусто - отдыхают путники, чабаны,
> благо живительный родник рядом (газ.);
> ...Игра свеч стоит - ведь такое
> общение должно стать прообразом
> будущих молодежных домов инженера и
> домов ученого (газ.); Сюда прибыли
> тысячи механизаторов - из России, с
> Украины, из Прибалтики (газ.).
>
> Схожее употребление знаков препинания
> найдем и у писателей, поэтов: У Блока
> было все, что создает великого поэта,
> - огонь, нежность, проникновение, свой образ мира, свой дар особого, все
> претворяющего прикосновения, своя
> сдержанная, скрадывающаяся,
> вобравшаяся в себя судьба (Паст.); Но
> вызывать сейчас огонь артиллерии было
> бессмысленно - огонь накрыл бы и наших
> разведчиков (Бонд.); Главный редактор
> газеты всячески избегает теперь
> встречи со мной, дозвониться ему
> невозможно, секретарша все ссылается
> на его занятость - то у него
> заседание, то планерка, то его вызвали
> в вышестоящие, как она любит
> подчеркивать, инстанции (Айтм.). Такие
> отклонения от правил выражают общие
> современные тенденции в развитии
> пунктуации и постепенно готовят почву
> для изменения или уточнения самих
> правил

Источник: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-060.htm

Соответственно, вопрос: корректно ли ставить тире вместо двоеточия, как описано выше, ведь это "тенденция"?

В другом источнике уже довольно четко прописано, что можно:

> 1. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с
>    причинно-следственными отношениями;
>    ср.: Последние дни флажки на карте не
>    двигались: положение оставалось без
>    перемен (Сим.). — А углубляться мы не
>    могли — земля промёрзла (Гран.).
>
> Ср. также: Кажется, Приморью и без
> того есть чем подивить мир (:— ) одни
> тигры да женьшень чего стоят; Эти
> слова при нём не произносите (: — )
> может обидеться; С таким напарником
> можно хоть на Марс лететь (: — )
> надёжный товарищ.

Источник: http://jewish-books.ru/rozental/spravochnik-po-russkomu-yazyku-punktuacziya/19/4.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос и заручились поддержкой Розенталя и Валгиной: "изменения в функционировании знаков происходят постоянно, они отражают жизнь языка, в частности его синтаксической структуры и стилистической системы.
Такие отклонения от правил выражают общие современные тенденции в развитии пунктуации и постепенно готовят почву для изменения или уточнения самих правил, К индивидуально-авторской пунктуации они не имеют никакого отношения".

Если не нравится двоеточие - заменяйте его на тире в перечисленных случаях. Правда, смотря что Вы пишете. Если это экзамен или контрольная работа, лучше соблюдать уже узаконенные нормы, если же творческую работу не для проверки на грамотность, пожалуйста,никто не запрещает, это современная тенденция.

Comment: Нет, это художественный текст (сетература), но мне несколько раз указывали на эту "ошибку", поэтому я порылась в интернете и решила на всякий случай посоветоваться (вдруг бы меня в ответ забили более значимыми источниками?)

Answer (score 4):

1. Двоеточие в БСП применяется для выражения: изъяснительных, пояснительных и следственно-причинных  отношений. 
   А) Я знал: удар судьбы меня не обойдёт. Оборачиваюсь: Грушницкий! 
   Б) В доме мало-помалу нарушалась тишина: где-то скрипнула дверь, послышались чьи-то шаги. Одно в нём нехорошо: уж очень был падок на деньги.
   В) Я не мог заснуть: передо мной во мраке всё вертелся мальчик с белыми глазами.
   Постановка двоеточия соответствует    пояснительной интонации: понижение тона перед значительно увеличенной (предупреждающей о пояснении) паузой.
2. Для современного языка характерна замена двоеточия на тире во всех его значениях. Возможно, это связано с динамичностью  нашей речи, отсутствием в ней обстоятельных и неспешных описаний. Однако замена должна быть обоснованной, так как при этом изменяется интонация предложения и появляются новые оттенки значений.
3. Тире выражает два вида интонации: разделительную и присоединительную.
   А) Замена  двоеточия на тире при выражении ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫХ ОТНОШЕНИЙ связана с УСКОРЕННЫМ ТЕМПОМ РЕЧИ И ЭФФЕКТОМ ПРИСУТСТВИЯ АВТОРА В МОМЕНТ СОВЕРШЕНИЯ СОБЫТИЙ: Ясно одно – оставаться здесь опасно. Вижу – дело плохо! Оглянулся – за ним стоял Серёжа в длинной рубашке, босой и с завязанным горлом.  Здесь разделительная интонация.
   Б) Замена  двоеточия на тире при выражении ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫХ ОТНОШЕНИЙ связана с ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫМ характером сообщения: Всё стало понятно – на поляне кормилась лошадь, а где-то здесь, рядом, кто-то ночевал. Здесь отсутствует увеличенная пауза.
   В) Замена  двоеточия на тире при выражении СЛЕДСТВЕННО-ПРИЧИННЫХ отношений связана с ДОБАВОЧНЫМ характером сообщения, характерным ДЛЯ ПРИСОЕДИНЕНИЯ: На этой земле никто не захотел селиться – она оказалась слишком скудной. Пора ехать – всё уже готово. Здесь также отсутствует предупредительная пауза
4. Обычно замена двоеточия на тире делается интуитивно и называется авторской. Однако при внимательном наблюдении  за художественными текстами можно отметить, что при определенной структуре текста желательно писать только двоеточие, например:  Отроду я не бывал в таких пустых местах: нигде не  мерцал огонёк, не слышалось никакого звука. А к нам идёт угрюмая зима: засохла степь, лес  глохнет и желтеет.

ОТВЕТ 2. Проведем эксперимент. Возьмем предложение: "Оборачиваюсь: Грушницкий!» Согласно современной тенденции заменяем двоеточие на тире. "Оборачиваюсь - Грушницкий!" И что получаем? В первом варианте герой оборачивается не спеша, с достоинством - поэтому пауза в тексте, поэтому двоеточие. Во втором случае мы, скорее,  описываем драматическую ситуацию, как будто он не стоит, рассматривая отдыхающих, а очень взволнован, очень куда-то торопится, убегает от кого-то.

А теперь попробуйте кому-нибудь объяснить, что пунктуация может выражать динамику пространства. Вряд ли вы встретите даже отдаленное понимание, и поэтому должны  будете услужливо рыться в правилах в поисках того, чего там нет.

Хорошо было Лермонтову писать свои романы! Все знаки препинания ему подсказывал его художественный вкус и чувство формы,  которая способна  выражать самые разнообразные оттенки мысли. У нас ему пришлось бы заручаться поддержкой Розенталя и Валгиной. Мне кажется, и нам желательно было бы иметь  больше смелости  и самостоятельности, чтобы защищать свое мнение, а заодно и всю русскую словесность от канцелярщины. Иначе говоря, «не надо прогибаться» под кого-то, пусть лучше они «прогнутся под нас».

ОТВЕТ 3.Да я ровно об этом и говорю. Разное содержание, разный стиль должны иметь свою форму выражения, но следует для себя понимать и уметь другим уметь объяснить, что выражает каждая форма. Это надо не только интуитивно чувствовать, но и уметь выразить словесно. И главное, для этого не надо обращаться к ссылкам, чтобы заручиться "поддержкой", а надо просто это знать. Например, вопрос:Почему вы заменили двоеточие на тире? Ответ: Я меняю классическое  двоеточие на тире, потому что отсутствие пояснительной паузы и повышение тона в конце отрезка речи мне необходимо для передачи повышенной динамики текста. А многоточием (еще более длинная пауза)я изображаю  очень медленное движение, и т.д. И еще: хочется сравнить литературное творчество с художественным. Там художник не обращается к ссылкам, чтобы выбрать нужную краску. Очень бы хотелось, чтобы литература была в этом похожа на живопись.

ОТВЕТ ЗАКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ.
Я, действительно, не поняла масштаба Вашего вопроса, а то бы и отвечать не стала. В вашей ситуации без ссылок, конечно, не обойтись. Только вот фраза "Вопрос заключался не в том, почему я это делаю, а в том, можно ли это вообще сделать теоретически" мне не кажется справедливой. Ни о какой теории в нашей орфографии и речи пока нет. Есть только наблюдения, которые мы называем орфографическими правилами, но теоретически мы их никак не объясняем. Не выросли еще из описательного периода нашей науки. Но Вас, а также многих других, это мало, к сожалению,  волнует.

Comment: Вы одного не учитываете. Современный стиль написания - именно легкий и динамичный, мысли героя бегут вперед со сверхзвуковой скоростью. Тут не идет речь ни о каком "с достоинством" и "не спеша". Литература за годы изменилась. А если взять сетературу, так там вообще ритм другой, иного читать не будут.
А если я, как автор, захочу сделать именно паузу, так я ее и сделаю. К примеру, поставлю вообще троеточие. "Оборачиваюсь... Грушницкий". Или в роковой сцене вообще использую короткие рубленные фразы.
"Звук выстрела оглушает. Оборачиваюсь.
Он.
Роняет пистолет.
Падает."

Comment: Вы опять не о том говорите. Вопрос заключался не в том, почему я это делаю, а в том, можно ли это вообще сделать теоретически. Ведь если я захочу заменить букву "о" на "а" в слове "кот", как бы я не хотела, это все равно будет ошибкой, даже если я скажу, что это дает слову большую эмоциональную окраску. Поэтому вопрос состоял в том, допустимо ли вообще (поэтому и ссылки).

Конкретно - ко мне обратился человек, заявляя, что этого делать нельзя вообще, что это ошибка. Я так не считаю, меня в школе по-другому учили, поэтому я собрала ссылки и обратилась за советом.