# Как объяснить выбор тире, а не двоеточия?

Tags: тире-или-двоеточие, интонация

**Вот примеры:**

1) Явное пояснение, раскрытие содержания:

**Эраст Петрович с председателем совета министров был знаком — несколько раз по его просьбе участвовал в головоломных или особенно деликатных расследованиях государственного значения.**

2) Явное указание причины во второй части:

**Бывало, что Эраст Петрович  отказывался — его представления о добре и зле не всегда совпадали с правительственными.**

Я решаю такие задачи с помощью интонационного анализа. Но если не применять такой анализ, то как здесь объяснить постановку тире?  И как  писатели выбирают нужный знак?

Comment: Был похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26338/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с конца:

> 4) А как писатели выбирают двоеточие или тире? Интуитивно, конечно. Они-то интонацию чувствуют и понимают, какие семантические оттенки содержит каждый знак

Почему "они-то"? Ну, ясно почему: потому что таланты, гении и все такое прочее. Разумеется, они чувствуют и понимают. Только есть небольшая закавыка: чувствуют они немножко по-разному, один Алексей Максимович чего стоит. А правы все – просто по определению. Не может же быть неправ Горький или, там, Паустовский...Но рядовому любителю словесности (или, скажем, школьнику) не стоит брать пример с гениев – он должен читать учебники и справочники, вот и выучится грамоте. Без всякого интонационного анализа. В школе квантовую механику не преподают? – Вот и интонационный анализ тоже. Ничего, живём.

Comment: Так зачем рядовым любителям словесности (или, скажем, школьникам)  учить два десятка правил про тире и двоеточие, если они без проблем заменяют друг друга. Лучше бы еще чего-нибудь выучили, а учителям пусть покажут правило ПАС: допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия во всех его значениях. А кто посмелее, тот пусть так и спросит: зачем мне нужны все эти правила, я буду тире и двоеточие  в тексте по очереди ставить. Как Вам такое решение, по-моему хороший вариант.

Comment: Зачем? Ответ такой же, что и на вопрос: "зачем мне нужны эти синусы и косинусы". Ответ – затем, что это развивает мозг. Там – логика математики, здесь – логика языка. В школах дают такие примеры, где двоеточие на тире заменить нельзя. А на факультативе любознательным ученикам скажем: да, в современном языке есть вот такая тенденция – во многих случаях тире вытесняет двоеточие. И никакой, повторюсь, "интонации"!

Comment: В школах нужно не примеры от учителя получать, где двоеточие на тире заменить нельзя, а классику читать. В художественной литературе 19-20 в.в. тире применялось в любых конструкциях, в том числе со значением пояснения, изъяснения и причины, это не только современная тенденция Зачем учить тому, что не соответствует жизни. И  при зубрежке правил мозг не развивается, а атрофируется.  Какая уж там логика ! Кстати, сочетание "перечислительная интонация" слышали? Тоже отменим? Вот Вы можете дать для такой интонации определение? А кто-нибудь из школьников это сделает? Как можно так учить!

Comment: Современные справочники "не соответствуют жизни"? Только потому, что там не уделяется должного, по вашему мнению, внимания интонации? Это сильно сказано... Сочетание "перечислительная интонация" слышал. Строгое определение давать не нужно, достаточно пояснить на примерах, и все будет понятно. У нас же не аксиоматический подход? Отменять не надо. Но и выпячивать тоже. А где я призываю к "зубрежке"?

Comment: Ладно, что нам ссориться из-за интонации, не стоит она этого. Хотите, вот лично для Вас я ее отменяю. Совсем! Как Вы там сказали: и никакой интонации! Никому это неинтересно и не нужно, а ненужный материал приговаривается к удалению. Считайте, что Общество Вас поддержало. Вот пройдусь по ночному городу, а потом всё это  "делитом и в баскет".

Comment: Оказывается, удалять вопросы с полученными ответами не рекомендуется. Ну да ладно, я его исправлю так, что останется только начало и конец. Вы ведь не обидитесь, не правда ли?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, следует начать с того, что  понятие нормы (и пунктуационной в том числе) исторически изменчиво. Создается литературный язык обычно передовой, культурной частью общества, писателями. Они первые почувствовали тенденцию языка к **вариативности**, динамичности, расчленённости. Динамичность и расчленённость передаётся как раз с помощью тире, которое иногда заменяет двоеточие и другие знаки препинания. Индивидуальный стиль писателя зависит от его пристрастий: если ему важна логика мысли, его пунктуация чаще соответствует Правилам 1956 года, если важна экспрессия - там будут тире.

Вариативность тире и двоеточия закреплена уже у Розенталя:

**§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания.**

Самые многочисленные случаи вариативности знаков препинания — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире[34].

1.После обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения часто ставится тире (вместо обычного двоеточия): Там всё иное — язык, уклад жизни, круг людей (Коч.); Всё в них выражало неприязнь — их крикливость, самоуверенность, бесцеремонность (Гран.).

Ср. примеры, где возможен выбор между двоеточием и тире: Его ничто не берёт (: —) ни время, ни невзгоды, ни болезни; Конечно, он изменился (: —) сгорбился, поседел, с морщинками в уголках рта; Трудно объяснить, чем он привлекал к себе (: —) интеллигентностью? свободными манерами? искренностью? добротой?; Но почему он так властвовал над умами и сердцами (: —) радовал и печалил, наказывал и прощал?, Мы оба художники (: —) и ты и я. [См. также § 15, п. 5 и 9.]

2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении с изъяснительными отношениями встречается наряду с двоеточием также тире. Ср.:
   *Я понял: важно, кто рисует (Гран.); Я понял — случилось горе, и молча хотел помочь (Ес.);*

*И судьи решили: если будет дождь, соревнования отменят; Заметил первый камень, решил — здесь клад, стал ковыряться (Тендр.).*

3. Вариативным стало употребление двоеточия и тире в эллиптических предложениях с отсутствующим глаголом восприятия (и увидел, и услышал, и почувствовал и т. п.)]. Ср.: *Прислушался: в горах было тихо (Горб.); Прислушался — вековечная лесная тишина (Сер.)*;

*Кузьма прислушался: кто-то погонял лошадь (Льв.); Якоб прислушался — невесёлая песня (Герм.).*

Ср. также: *Вхожу (: —) всё тихо; Он всё время озирается (: —) не подкрадывается ли кто-нибудь; Рассчитал, прикинул (: —) невыгодно; Он с удивлением смотрел на пятна (: —) это откуда? [*См. § 44, п. 4.]

Ср. постановку тире (вместо ожидаемого двоеточия) в предложениях этого типа: *Он искоса посмотрел на неё — она очень молода и красива (М. Г.); Она оглянулась — на неё летела Васька в солдатской гимнастёрке, с угольно-чёрными бровями от переносья до висков (Пан.); Он выглянул из комнаты — ни одного огонька в окнах (Пан.); Посмотрел на прорубь — вода дремала (Шишк.).*

Иногда в этих случаях вместо двоеточия употребляются запятая и тире как единый знак препинания: *Я заглянул в гнёздышко, — там всего два птенчика (Вер.); Я обернулся, — всадник уже рядом (С об.); Поднял глаза, — стул подле стола был пустой (Сер.).*

4. **Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с причинно-следственными отношениями**.

   Ср.: *Кажется, Приморью и без того есть чем подивить мир (: —)одни тигры да женьшень чего стоят; Эти слова при нём не произносите (: —) может обидеться; С таким напарником можно хоть на Марс лететь (: —) надёжный товарищ.*
5. **Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями:**

   *Авторов этих писем волновали разные проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения; Я помню пушок на его щеках (: —) он только начал бриться; На голове её цветной платок (: —) по алому полю зелёные розы; У меня правило (: —) никакого кофепития перед сном.*
6. **Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается при обособлении пояснительных и уточняющих членов предложения**:

*Это означало одно (: —) нужно расстаться; Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, десять?; Потом началось главное (: —)поиски, нащупывание новых путей исследования; Кончался их разговор всегда одним и тем же (: —) ссорой; Сколько мне тогда было (: —) девятнадцать или двадцать?; Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) в среду или в четверг.*

В «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия» и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире». Объяснить это можно особым статусом тире среди других знаков препинания: «В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе»[38].

Наблюдения над современной периодической печатью подтверждают вывод об «агрессивности» тире: За годы, прошедшие со времени подписания Заключительного акта в Хельсинки, миллионы людей, прежде всего в Европе, лично сумели оценить всё то доброе, что дала им разрядка, — преимущества мирной спокойной жизни, экономического, научно-технического и культурного сотрудничества (Газ.); Выборы позади — можно отдохнуть (Газ.). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

http://miassats.ru/2875/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я думаю другим будет интересно почитать материал на эту тему, меня же интересует только эти два предложения. Просто очень коротко: почему автор выбрал в этих случаях именно тире?

Comment: Ну, про выбор именно в этих предложениях нужно спросить у самого Б. Акунина, а вообще - он любитель динамичной экспрессивной речи, у него много парцеллированных конструкций. К тому же нужно иметь в виду, что романы о Фандорине - литературная игра. Лексика создаёт стиль 19 века, стиль Шмелёва, а синтаксис - от постмодерна, постмодернизм  использует в основном  синтаксис современный, значит, тире ему больше присуще, чем классическое двоеточие. Это языковой портрет автора. Случаи эти как раз допускают вариативность, вот и использовал тире как указание на паузу, придав значительности второй части.

Comment: А что бы изменилось, если в этом предложении поставить двоеточие (оно, кстати, обозначает более длительную паузу)?  Как знак влияет на прочтение предложения и на его семантику? В этих предложениях я не вижу особой экспрессии как признака постмодернизма. Классики 19 века также часто использовали тире вместо двоеточия. Надо просто знать семантические и интонац.  особенности знаков, а об этом в учебниках ничего не говорится, одни общие фразы о современном синтаксисе. Двоеточие не так уж часто используется, нужно изучать случаи обязательного употребления знаков, а не  те случаи, где есть варианты.

Comment: О судьбе тире и двоеточия пишет Валгина, она утверждает, что тире приобрело универсальность, поэтому в указанных Вами примерах оно обозначает то же, что двоеточие, двоеточие обязательно только в случае, если в первой части есть указательные слова так, такой и т.д. http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tire-70386.html

Comment: Жаль, что Валгина не говорит о том, что по интонации это разные знаки, и читать их надо по-разному. Хотя бы из-за этого не стоит считать, что значение у них одинаковое.